# Music apps in html 5 on my website

Tags: html, spotify, audio-player, mashup

I am making a website where I include all multimedia and social media services like Youtube, Facebook, Dailymotion etc. I am already done with the mentioned three.I want to include a free music servicewith a html 5 interface for the music player and if possible would want to stick to Javascript APIs. I have been reading about spotify, but the developer account needs to have a premium account.

Could someone suggest any music services along with a reference for the apis?

## EDIT

Most of the online audio streaming services I have come across require flash to play in a browser.I have tried at least 20. I want to play the music in HTML5 on my browser in my web application. I still have absolutely no clue which services I should look into.

Comment: This question is too broad/subjective

Answer (score 0):

Google is your friend. There are only a handful of streaming music services with APIs. I believe you could have got this answer yourself.

Try Rdio, it seems they are more relaxed about giving developer accounts to their API.

http://developer.rdio.com/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It looks very very promising, but it seems it must have a flash front end and not a html5 one.